# Retrofit_2 http POST return 403 message

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to convert Java source code to Android. This is Java code which execute http POST then receive data as json. And it works well.

```
public String httpPost(){
String url = "https://webapi.com/api?" 
  List<NameValuePair> params; 
  List<NameValuePair> headers;

  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", commandValue));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nonce", 
  String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));

  headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", API_KEY));
  headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sign", SECRET_SIGNATURE);

  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, Consts.UTF_8));
        String str = post.getEntity().toString();

        if (headers != null)
        {
            for (NameValuePair header : headers)
            {
                post.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
            }
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null)
        {
           return  EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }

    return null;
   }
```

This is Android source code using Retrofit 2:
APIServiceInterface.java

```
 @POST("api")
    Call<Mymodel> httpPost(@Header("Key") String key,
                                                 @Header("Sign") String sign,
                                                 @Query("command") String command,
                                                 @Query("nonce") String nonce);
```

APIClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

POST request

```
    String url = "https://webapi.com/";
    APIServiceInterface apiService =   ApiClient.getClient(url).create(APIServiceInterface.class);
    Call<MyModel> call = apiService.httpPost(apiKey, secretSignature, commandValue,  String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<MyModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyModel> call, Response<MyModel> response) {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                        Log.d(TAG,"http  POST:\n[header]:\n" + call.request().headers() +
                    "\n[request]:\n" + call.request().toString() +
                    "\n[body]: \n" + call.request().body().toString()+
                    "\n----------------------------------------------"+
                    "\nResponse:\n[header]:\n" + response.headers() +
                    "\n[body]:\n"+ response.body() +
                    "\n[raw]:" + response.raw() +
                    "\n[status] :" + response.code() +
                    "\n[message] :" + response.message());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    // Log error here since request failed
                    Log.e(TAG, "Request failed :" + t.toString());
                }
            });
```

This is debug log

```
http  POST:
[header]:
Key: MHKVXY9C-9WE8N6CS-L1ETB10V-TFUA4S8G
Sign: 2534CCB0C58850B4FA621539D5AA5ACB0433B8F47070E6ED13757006F85FF1E4244D3118BDE107C46A7F5587C06BA201F74DE10003330ECBD352757D23E57ACA

[request]:
Request{method=POST, url=https://webapi.com/api?command=commandValue&nonce=nonceValue, tag=null}
[body]: 
okhttp3.RequestBody$2@1751ef1
----------------------------------------------
Response:
[header]:
date: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 07:07:50 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d0c467a5dbc10a660a569227616baa28f1512457670; expires=Wed, 05-Dec-18 07:07:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.webapi.com; HttpOnly
cf-chl-bypass: 1
cache-control: max-age=2
expires: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 07:07:52 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
server: cloudflare-nginx
cf-ray: 3c852bb78ea732ef-HKG

[body]:
null
[raw]:Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=https://webapi.com/api?command=commandValue&nonce=nonceValue}
[status] :403
[message] :
```

However the Android source code doesn't work, it always return 403 message.
Is my code wrong somewhere?
 
Could anyone help me! Thanks.

Comment: provide full error with logcat

Comment: I updated my question with debug log, please take a look . I think that something is wrong with the post header, maybe something is missing but I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Verify `Key` & `Sign` headers from server first.

> The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

Verify headers which you are passing and content-type, then test in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) see if works.

If your api doesn't work in postman then there is nothing you can do in Android to make it work.

---

**UPDATE**

try passing header along with http client,

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Key", API_KEY)
                .header("Sign", SECRET_SIGNATURE);
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json"); // set your content type

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
```

> Post API should be

```
 @POST("api")
Call<Mymodel> httpPost(
                       @Query("command") String command,
                       @Query("nonce") String nonce);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your credentials may be correct but you are getting Error 403 from CloudFlare server(cloudflare-nginx) not from your server(webapi).
Your request needs to make it through cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

Add header **Content-Type: application/json** on request.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("blue_lagoon_api/webservice/login")
Call<LoginResponse> callLoginApi(@Body LoginParameter loginParameter);
```